# Getting message activemq consumer.receive()?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

[This code](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) uses threads and works as expected 
but I am trying to do the same thing without threads.

first I am sending 10 messages

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String msg = "ABCD" + i;
            TextMessage textMessage = Communication._getInstance().session.createTextMessage(msg);
            textMessage.setJMSType(msg);
            Communication._getInstance().getProducer().send(textMessage);
        }
```

Receiving 10 messages here.

```
 public static ArrayList messages() {
    EFLogger.LogInfo("MessageProcessor", "in messsages method");

    ArrayList msg = new ArrayList();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Message message = Communication._getInstance().getConsumer().receive(2000);

            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {

                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                msg.add(textMessage.getJMSType());
            } else {
                EFLogger.LogInfo("MessageProcessor", "Received: " + message);
            }
            Communication._getInstance().session.close();
            Communication._getInstance().connection.close();
        }


    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

But I get the only first message and other messages are not even `instanceof TextMessage` and shows null

**note:** Tried both closing connection each time and after receiving messages, results stay the same.

**logs**

```
Message Received JMSType [ ABCD1 ] Text [ ABCD1 ] | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:51,596 | INFO  | Closing the connection | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:53,640 | INFO  | Received: null | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:53,640 | INFO  | Closing the connection | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:55,659 | INFO  | Received: null | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:55,660 | INFO  | Closing the connection | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:57,676 | INFO  | Received: null | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:57,676 | INFO  | Closing the connection | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:59,689 | INFO  | Received: null | root | main
2016-10-07 12:24:59,689 | INFO  | Closing the connection | root | main
```

Comment: It's quite hard for anyone to know what your `Communication._getInctance().getConsumer().receive(2000)` does - perhaps it's buggy. or perhaps the number 2000 is a timeout, and you hit that timeout. You are also  calling `Communication._getInctance().session.close();` , so one would guess that you close both your session and the connection to the message service after the first iteration in your loop - which at a glance sounds wrong.

Comment: I am using the singleton to get the consumer object. And yes 2000 is a timeout and I tried increasing it but no luck. As I have mentioned in the question, I have tried both ways by closing the connection on each iteration or after everything or not even closing the connection.